# Click form on click of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

In this when I click on "Upload Photo" I want that the form's "Choose File" be clicked.I want to hide the form and trigger the form through click of "Upload Photo".How can I achieve this (without using label)?

HTML:

```
 <div id="image_container" name="image_container">
            <img src="../image/ab.jpg"  alt="Cover" width="900px" height="500px">
            <div class="btn-group" id="cov" name="cov" >
               <button  class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="mybtn" onclick="dropdown()">Action</button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
                <li><a href="">Upload Photo</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">  
                    <input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file" />
                    <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
                    <img src="img/loader.gif" id="loading-img" style="display:none;" alt="Please Wait"/>
                    </form>
<div id="output"></div>


JS:

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
            target: '#output', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit, // pre-submit callback 
            success: afterSuccess, // post-submit callback 
            resetForm: true // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 

        $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
            // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
            return false; 
        }); 
    });

    function uploadfile(){
        $("imageInput").click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work (assuming the "Upload Photo"-text is a link):

```
$('#upload-photo-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#imageInput').trigger('click');
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/EvNLQ/

Comment: I figured out my problem.Thanks by the way, for your time.